# Airflow: how to download PDF files from S3 bucket into Airflow

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

tried below code but getting error as "unable to locate Credentials"
def download():

```
bucket = 'bucketname'
key = 'path and filename'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)
objects = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key)
for obj = objects:
    path,filename = os.path.split(obj.key)
    my_bucket.download_file(obj.key, filename)
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to define the AWS connection and use
`download_fileobj` function via the `S3Hook`.

I didn't test it but it should be something like:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
hook = S3Hook('my_aws_conn')
key_object = hook.get_key('your_path')
with NamedTemporaryFile("wb") as f:
     key_object.download_fileobj(Fileobj=f)
     f.flush()
```

Comment: it looks like S3Hook for newer version doesn't contain download_fileobj method. Any alternative to that ?